# Erlang rr() returns missing_chunk

Tags: erlang

Newbie question on erlang using by wings 3d shell (windows 7 pro, wings 3d 1.4.1). When I write command to read records definitons:

```
    rr(wings).
```

I always get an error:

```
    {error,beam_lib,
      {missing_chunk,'d:/temp/erlang/lib/wings/ebin/wings.beam',"Abst"}}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This must be a PATHS problem. Is the .hrl file on D: or d: , windows drives can be case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

rr/1 "reads record definitions from a module's BEAM file. If there are no record definitions in the BEAM file, the source file is located and read instead."

My guess is that the abstract form hasn't been included in the .BEAM file and that in your installation the source files are not available.

**UPDATE:** Digging into the `shell:read_file_records/2` function, I've found the following:

```
read_file_records(File, Opts) ->
    case filename:extension(File) of
        ".beam" ->
            case beam_lib:chunks(File, [abstract_code,"CInf"]) of
                {ok,{_Mod,[{abstract_code,{Version,Forms}},{"CInf",CB}]}} ->
                    case record_attrs(Forms) of
                        [] when Version =:= raw_abstract_v1 ->
                            [];
                        [] -> 
                            %% If the version is raw_X, then this test
                            %% is unnecessary.
                            try_source(File, CB);
                        Records -> 
                            Records
                    end;
                {ok,{_Mod,[{abstract_code,no_abstract_code},{"CInf",CB}]}} ->
                    try_source(File, CB);
                Error ->
                    %% Could be that the "Abst" chunk is missing (pre R6).
                    Error
            end;
        _ ->
            parse_file(File, Opts)
    end.
```

It looks like, if the "Abst" chunk is missing, it doesn't even try to read the source code. What does `beam_lib:chunks(File, [abstract_code,"CInf"])` return for you? Which Erlang version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I am using:

```
Erlang R14B01 (erts-5.8.2) [rq:1] [async-threads:0]
Eshell V5.8.2  (abort with ^G)
```

Calling this works fine:

```
    rr("d:/temp/erlang/src/wings.hrl").
```

Calling:

```
    beam_lib:chunks("wings", [abstract_code,"CInf"]).
```

returns:

```
    {error,beam_lib,{file_error,"wings.beam",enoent}}
```

Answer (score 0):

rr/1 requires the actual file name or the relative PATH to the file name. Like this:

```
rr("wings.hrl").

OR

rr("./apps/MYAPP-1.0/include/my_include_file.hrl").

OR

rr("./src/wings.erl").
```

In other words, pass it the actual relative PATH from your `pwd()` to the file which contains the definitions.

Comment: There's also a variant of rr/1 which accepts an atom, which is what @mbr is using. rr("wings.hrl") should allow him to read the record definitions, but it would be nice to understand why that variant doesn't work.

Comment: This makes it a File PATHS problem. Otherwise, it means that the function rr/1 has side effects. Which of these could it be?